# TextExpander Performance Issues - Windows

Tags: windows, autohotkey, textexpander

I have been looking all over online to see if anyone has been experiencing performance issues with their TextExpander snippet expansion.

For example, on my Mac my snippets expand just fine, it's fast and fluid. However, anytime I use my Windows Laptop it takes a lot longer to expand normally. On my web browser I do use the plugin which makes it run normally but I wish that it would run just as fast on my other desktop applications. It just isn't going as fast as AutoHotKey or PhraseExpress would on my computer.

I've also see it sometimes add a random letter to the end of my snippets after expansion and I don't know why it does that. I tried upgrading my ram from 16 to 32GB and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to run the program as administrator?

Comment: I haven’t because I don’t have admin privileges on my laptop. Could you clarify how that could help?

Comment: We need more details about that program. Why the tag "autohotkey"? Is your TextExpander an autohotkey script?

Comment: Try also to [change its priority](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Process-Priorities-in-Windows-Task-Manager).

Comment: It's because AutoHotKey has similar functionality and wanted to see if members of that community may have a solution as well.